# Android sending email SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, android, email

I have this android application that I want to send an email to the user once the user has successfully registered. I am not able to send the email, though. After I click "Submit" and Im redirected to the Home activity as a successfully logged in user, I  wait for about 10 seconds and then a yellow error message appears in the logcat saying that mail has not been sent.

This is where I trigger sending the email:

```
public class Signup extends Activity implements OnUserCreatedListener {
    @Override
    public void onUserCreated(Integer userId) {

        editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("userLoggedInState", true);
        editor.putInt("currentLoggedInUserId", userId);
        editor.commit();

        Intent signupSuccessHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        signupSuccessHome.putExtra("reqFrom", "signup");
        startActivity(signupSuccessHome);

        try {
            new EmailSender(userEmail, Configurationz.Emailz.OFFICIAL_ADDRESS, Configurationz.Emailz.SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP_SUBJECT, Configurationz.Emailz.SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP_BODY(userName), null).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        finish();
    }
```

This is the EmailSender Utility Class

```
public class EmailSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    String to;
    String from;
    String subject;
    String message;
    String[] attachments;
    Mail mail = new net.asdasd.utilities.Mail();

    public  EmailSender(String to, String from, String subject, String message, String[] attachments) {
        super();
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (subject != null && subject.length() > 0) {
            mail.setSubject(subject);
        } else {
            mail.setSubject("Subject");
        }

        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            mail.setBody(message);
        } else {
            mail.setBody("Message");
        }
        mail.setTo(to);
        mail.setFrom(from);
        try {
            return mail.send();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the mail class:

```
package net.asdasd.utilities;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import net.shiftinpower.configuration.Configurationz;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    public String user;
    public String password;
    private String to;
    private String from;
    private String port;
    private String sport;
    private String host;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    private boolean _auth;
    private boolean _debuggable;
    private Multipart multipart;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Multipart getMultipart() {
        return multipart;
    }

    public void setMultipart(Multipart multipart) {
        this.multipart = multipart;
    }
    public Mail() {

        host = "smtp.googlemail.com"; // default smtp server
        port = "465"; // default smtp port
        sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port
        user = Configurationz.Emailz.ASDASD_OFFICIAL_ADDRESS; 
        password = Configurationz.Emailz.ASDASD_OFFICIAL_PASSWORD;     
        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!user.equals("") && !password.equals("") && to.length() > 0 && !from.equals("") && !subject.equals("") && !body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < to.length(); i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        return props;
    } 
    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }
    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this.body = _body;
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.googlemail.com, port: 465;
   nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at net.asdasd.utilities.Mail.send(Mail.java:120)
    at net.asdasd.utilities.EmailSender.doInBackground(EmailSender.java:38)
    at net.asdasd.utilities.EmailSender.doInBackground(EmailSender.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:945)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
    ... 15 more
```

And this is the previous version of the class (and it worked)

```
public class EmailSender {
    public boolean sendEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String message, String[] attachements) throws Exception {
        Mail mail = new net.shiftinpower.utilities.Mail();
        if (subject != null && subject.length() > 0) {
            mail.setSubject(subject);
        } else {
            mail.setSubject("Subject");
        }

        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            mail.setBody(message);
        } else {
            mail.setBody("Message");
        }
        mail.setTo(to);
        mail.setFrom(from);
        return mail.send();

    }
}
```

I was also calling it in a different way:

In Signup.java:

```
private class sendVerificationEmail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            emailSender.sendEmail(userEmail, Configurationz.Emailz.ASDASD_OFFICIAL_ADDRESS, Configurationz.Emailz.SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP_SUBJECT, Configurationz.Emailz.SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP_BODY(userName), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
//blah blah
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ShowLoadingMessage.dismissDialog();



        try {
            new sendVerificationEmail().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that smtp.googlemail.com exists; please try smtp.gmail.com

Comment: I got the same error. BTW it used to work when i was using googlemail, but I made some refactoring today and it stopped working.